# CreateDirectory doesn't create a directory VS2017 c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directory

I'm trying to create a directory (if doesn't already exist) in my application and I'm using the CreateDirectory function, the problem is that it's not creating the folder:

```
string folderfile = "C:\\Screenshots";

CreateDirectory(LPCTSTR(folderfile.c_str()), NULL);
```

I'm executing Visual Studio in administrator mode.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Call a GetLastError()

Comment: Probably the cast to LPCTSTR. A string is not necessarily a sequence of TCHARs, it depends upon compiler settings.

Comment: Presumably you added the cast to remove a compiler error? It's a good lesson, you can force the compiler to accept your code usings casts, but the error was there for a reason. You need to fix the real issue, not just add a cast.

Comment: How could I pass the correctly the argument then? it doesn't let me even to pass the  literal "C:\\Screenshots"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the cast to `LPCTSTR` my crystal ball tells me the call to `CreateDirectory(folderfile.c_str(), NULL);` didn't compile for you. That's because Visual Studio by default compiles in *Unicode mode* and you need to use a `wstring`.

You have a few solutions:

1. Switch the project character set to *ANSI mode*:
   *Project properties* -> *General* -> *Character Set* -> *Use Multi-Byte Character set*
2. Call `CreateDirectoryA` explicitly:

   `string folderfile = "C:\\Screenshots";`
   `CreateDirectoryA(folderfile.c_str(), NULL);`
3. Keep using Unicode charset and use `wstring`:

   `wstring folderfile = L"C:\\Screenshots";`
   `CreateDirectory(folderfile.c_str(), NULL);`

Also don't forget to check the return value (`BOOL`) and call `GetLastError()` if it's `false`. That way you can find out *why* the call failed.

Comment: Thanks, your crystal ball works really well,  that solved the problem.